# Angular: Do not Display HTML Attribute if No Input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have a Component, where we want to Input an HTML attribute.

However if No value is provided for input, I do Not want even display the attribute in html. How can this be done? Right now it shows as "".

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input dataQA: string;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="productTitle"
    data-qa="dataQA"
>
```

**Note:** I want to keep the Whole Div, just exclude the attribute within the div. I may have multiple attributes future within the div, so looking for efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf="<condition>"` for that

IE:  `<div class="productTitle" data-qa="dataQA" *ngIf="dataQa">`

To apply an attribute dynamically, you can do something similar by using attribute bindings:

IE: `<p [attr.dataQA]="something ? null : ''">`

Explanation: `null` means attribute will not be applied. `''` (an empty string) applies the attribute without value (ie `dataQA` opposed to `dataQA="some value"`)

For a string in your example, it would be

```
<p [attr.test]="something ? something : null">
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jwvwhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I updated my answer. You want to use attribute bindings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngIf` for adding a conditional check. For your requirement you can add two separate HTML elements, one with attribute and one without attribute. Then applying condition on the elements.

Try this:

```
<div class="productTitle" [attr.data-qa]="dataQA || null"></div>
```

Comment: I want to keep the Whole Div, just exclude the attribute within the div. I may have multiple attributes future within the div, so looking for efficient solution.

Comment: Updated with attribute binding. You can remove the value of the attribute using that. But you can't remove the attribute.